# Can set variable on server in java socket

Tags: java, sockets

After solve my problem to handle add label into my jlabel backgroudn in previous question. I got new trouble when develop a client server in hang man for 2 players to play game.

Firstly when user choose mode 2 players. Client will send a message to Server is "twoPMode"

From TCP server , server receive this message and put it into a method handle input from client.

in this method, i have a global variable  called playerId and it has 2 method getter/stter

detail:

When user send message "twoPMode" to server, server will call this method and in this method it receive input from client and handle, if input from client is twoPMode it will set Playerid = "001" and if other client send message twoPMode to server it will set playerid = "002" , because i just want 2 client can connect to server to play game, if client 3 connect and send twoPMode to server i will destroy connection of client 3.

My trouble is when client 1 and client 2 send message twoPMode to server it also receive id is 001, it fail because i want who is connect to server first will get playerid is 001 and second is get player id is 002, but my code just respond to client is 001 although 2 clients connect to server

and my code - i delete some generate code from netbean to initial component

Server side:

class handle input from client

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package srpserver;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 *
 * @author J2ME NewBiew
 */
public class gameHandle {

    private static final int WAITING = 0;
    private static final int onePMode = 1;
    private static final int getWord = 2;
    private static final int PlayonePmode = 3;
    private static final int NUMJOKES = 5;
    private String keyword = "";
    private static final int mode = 4;
    private int state = WAITING;
    private int countError = 0;
    private String playerid = "000";

    public String getPlayerid() {
        return playerid;
    }


    //array word list
        String[] words = {"laptop", "network", "device", "game", "mobile",
    "word", "november", "december", "signal", "internet","localhost","boot", "socket",
    "client", "server", "port", "exception", "java", "dotnet","singleton", "ejb","hibernate",
    "computer", "microsoft", "lan"};

    //this method get random word from array    
    public String getWord(){
        Random r = new Random();
        String randomString = words[r.nextInt(words.length)];
        return randomString;
    }



    public String processInput(String theInput) {
        String theOutput = null;

        if (state == WAITING) {
            theOutput = "Hello Hangman Client";
            state = mode;
        } else if(state == mode){

            if(theInput.equalsIgnoreCase("onePMode")){
                theOutput = "onePMode" ;
                state = onePMode;
            }else if(theInput.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                state = WAITING;
            }else if(theInput.equalsIgnoreCase("twoPMode")){
               if(playerid.equals("000")){
                   setPlayerid("001");
                   theOutput = "001";
                   playerid = "001";
                   System.out.println("Thu cai coi 01");
               }
               else if(playerid.equals("001")){
                   setPlayerid("002");
                   theOutput = "002";
                   playerid = "002";
                   System.out.println("Thu cai coi 02");
               }

            }

        } else if (state == onePMode) {
            if (theInput.equalsIgnoreCase("getWord")) {
                keyword = getWord();
                theOutput = keyword;
                state = PlayonePmode;

            } 
        }else if (state == PlayonePmode) {
            if(theInput.equalsIgnoreCase("getWord")){
                theOutput = " chuyen sang getword";
                state = getWord;

            }else if (keyword.contains(theInput)) {
                theOutput = "containt";
            } else {
                if(countError <9){
                    theOutput = "Khong contain";
                     countError++;
                }else if(countError>=9){
                   theOutput = "Game Over!";
                }
            }
        }   if (state == getWord){
            keyword = getWord();
            theOutput = keyword;
            state = PlayonePmode;
        }
         System.out.println("Player ID: " +  playerid);
        return theOutput;
    }

    public void setPlayerid(String playerid) {
        this.playerid = playerid;
    }
}
```

Class server open thread, send data to client and receive data from client:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package srpserver;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 *
 * @author J2ME NewBiew
 */
public class TCPServerThread extends Thread{

    Socket client = null;
    BufferedReader in;
    String statusBuffer = new String();
    String intputLine, outputLine;
    public TCPServerThread(Socket socket){
        client = socket;
    }

    public void run(){

    try {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                    client.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine, outputLine;
        gameHandle g = new gameHandle();
        outputLine = g.processInput(null);
        out.println(outputLine);

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        outputLine = g.processInput(inputLine);
                System.out.println(outputLine);
                if(inputLine.equals("getWord")){
                    System.out.println(inputLine);
                }

        out.println(outputLine);
        if (inputLine.equals("Bye"))
            break;
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        client.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

}
```

Client side: i use 2 panel , one 1 home page of game and 1 is two players mode

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package srpclient.home;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import srpclient.ConnectionTCP;
import srpclient.about.aboutPanel;
import srpclient.player1.onePlayer;
import srpclient.twoplayers.twoPlayers;

/**
 *
 * @author J2ME NewBiew
 */
public final class Home extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    aboutPanel aboutPanel;
    onePlayer onePlayerMode;
    String serverAddress;
    twoPlayers twoPlayerMode;
     ConnectionTCP c;
    /**
     * Creates new form Home
     */
    public Home(String ipAddress) {
        initComponents();

         //conn = new ConnectionTCP(ipAddress);
         this.serverAddress = ipAddress;

         initialPanel();
       //  conn.closeConnection();

    }

    public void initialPanel(){
        aboutPanel = new aboutPanel();


    }

    public void changeImage(JButton bt, String imgPath){
        bt.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/"+imgPath+".jpg")));
    }

    public void setTooltipforButton(JButton bt, String Tooltip){
        bt.setToolTipText(Tooltip);
    }



    private void player1Hover(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        changeImage(btPlayer1, "player1Hover");
        setTooltipforButton(btPlayer1, "Play game with 1 player mode");
    }                             

    private void player1MouseExit(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        changeImage(btPlayer1, "player1");
    }                                 

    private void player2MouseHover(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        changeImage(btPlayer2, "player2Hover");
        setTooltipforButton(btPlayer2, "Play game with 2 players mode");
    }                                  

    private void player2MouseExit(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        changeImage(btPlayer2, "player2");

    }                                 

    private void ruleHover(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        changeImage(btRule, "ruleHover");
        setTooltipforButton(btRule, "Play this game with this rule");
    }                          

    private void ruleMouseExit(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                               
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        changeImage(btRule, "rule");
    }                              

    private void AboutMouseHover(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                 
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        changeImage(btAbout, "aboutHover");
        setTooltipforButton(btAbout, "About Me!!!!");
    }                                

    private void AboutMouseExit(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        changeImage(btAbout, "about");
    }                               

    private void enterAboutPanel(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                 
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        jDesktopRemoveAndRepaint();
        CallPanel(aboutPanel);

    }                                

    public void jDesktopRemoveAndRepaint(){
        jDesktopPane1.removeAll();
        jDesktopPane1.repaint();
        jDesktopPane1.revalidate();
    }

    public void CallPanel(JPanel panel){
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 840, 558);
        panel.setSize(840,558);
        jDesktopPane1.add(panel);
        panel.show();
    }

    private void enterToPlay1PlayerMode(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
        try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            c = new ConnectionTCP(serverAddress);
            onePlayerMode = new onePlayer(serverAddress);
            jDesktopRemoveAndRepaint();
            CallPanel(onePlayerMode);
            c.getOut().println("onePMode");


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Home.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }                                       

    private void btPlayer2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
       try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            c = new ConnectionTCP(serverAddress);           
            twoPlayerMode = new twoPlayers(serverAddress);
            jDesktopRemoveAndRepaint();

            String fromServer = c.getIn().readLine();


            c.getOut().println("twoPMode");
            twoPlayerMode.setPlayerID(fromServer);

            CallPanel(twoPlayerMode);





        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Home.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }                                         

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btAbout;
    private javax.swing.JButton btExit;
    private javax.swing.JButton btPlayer1;
    private javax.swing.JButton btPlayer2;
    private javax.swing.JButton btRule;
    private javax.swing.JDesktopPane jDesktopPane1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Panel 2 players

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package srpclient.twoplayers;

import srpclient.player1.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import srpclient.ConnectionTCP;

/**
 *
 * @author Kency
 */
public final class twoPlayers extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form onePlayer
     */
    ConnectionTCP conn;
    int countWrongLetter = 0;
    String getWord = "getWord";
    String serverAddress = "";
    JLabel lblKeyword[];
    String keyword = "";
    JLabel head  = new JLabel("");
     String sHead = "", sLeft_eye="", sRight_eye="", sBody="",
            sMouth="",sLeft_arm="",sRight_arm="",sLeft_leg="",sRight_leg="";
    Graphics g;
    String playerID = "";

    public String getPlayerID() {
        return playerID;
    }

    public void setPlayerID(String playerID) {
        this.playerID = playerID;
    }
    public twoPlayers(String serverAddress) {
        try {
            initComponents();
            jTextArea1.setEditable(false);
            conn = new ConnectionTCP(serverAddress);
            this.serverAddress = serverAddress;
            conn.getOut().println("twoPMode");

            if (conn.getIn().readLine() != null) {
                setPlayerID(conn.getIn().readLine());

                System.out.println(getPlayerID());
            }
            if(getPlayerID().equals("002")){
                jButton1.setEnabled(false);
                btPlay.setEnabled(false);
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(twoPlayers.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    private void getWordLabels(String keyword) {
        int length = keyword.length();
        lblKeyword = new JLabel[length];
        int widhLebelKeyword = 100;
        int heightLabelKeyword = 20;
        int gapbetweenLetter = 350/length;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {          

            lblKeyword[i] = new JLabel("_");
            jLabel1.revalidate();
            jLabel1.repaint();
            lblKeyword[i].setForeground(Color.white);
            lblKeyword[i].setBounds((gapbetweenLetter * i + 100), 300, widhLebelKeyword, heightLabelKeyword);
            jLabel1.add(lblKeyword[i]);
        }
    }








     enum BodyPart { 
            Head,
            Left_Eye,
            Right_Eye,
            Mouth,
            Body,
            Left_Arm,
            Right_Arm,
            Left_Leg,
            Right_Leg
        }


      void DrawBodyPart(BodyPart bp)
        {
            Graphics g = this.getGraphics();
            g.setColor(Color.white);

            if(bp == BodyPart.Head)// draw a head
            {
                 g.drawOval(570, 160, 70, 70);
            }else if(bp == BodyPart.Left_Eye){
                g.drawLine(580, 180, 590, 185);
                g.drawLine(590, 180, 580, 185);
            }else if(bp == BodyPart.Right_Eye){
                g.drawLine(620, 180, 630, 185);
                g.drawLine(630, 180, 620, 185);
            }else if(bp ==BodyPart.Mouth){
                g.drawArc(575, 200, 60, 50, 45, 90);
            }else if(bp == BodyPart.Body){
                 g.drawLine(605, 230, 605 , 310);
            }else if(bp == BodyPart.Left_Arm){
                 g.drawLine(550, 260, 605, 230 );
            }else if(bp == BodyPart.Right_Arm){
                g.drawLine(660, 260, 605, 230 );
            }else if(bp == BodyPart.Left_Leg){
                 g.drawLine(550, 350, 605, 310 );
            }else if(bp == BodyPart.Right_Leg){
                g.drawLine(605, 310, 660, 350 );     
            }

        }




    //get Keyword from server
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:

            conn.getOut().println(getWord);
            String inputFromServer = conn.getIn().readLine();
            System.out.println(inputFromServer);
            keyword = inputFromServer;
            getWordLabels(keyword);
            jButton1.setEnabled(false);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(twoPlayers.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }                                        

    //compare letter with word, if contain show it on jlabel
    private void searchLetter(){
        String  let = txtLetter.getText();
        char letter = let.toCharArray()[0];
        int length = keyword.length();
        lblKeyword = new JLabel[length];
        int widhLebelKeyword = 100;
        int heightLabelKeyword = 20;
        int gapbetweenLetter = 350/length;


        if(keyword.contains(let)){
            char[] letters = keyword.toCharArray();
            for(int i = 0 ; i < letters.length; i++){
            lblKeyword[i] = new JLabel("_");
            //jLabel1.revalidate();
            jLabel1.repaint();
            lblKeyword[i].setForeground(Color.white);
            lblKeyword[i].setBounds((gapbetweenLetter * i + 100), 300, widhLebelKeyword, heightLabelKeyword);

                if(letters[i] == letter)            {

                    lblKeyword[i].setText(Character.toString(letter));
                     jLabel1.add(lblKeyword[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //wrong letter not contain in keyword will keep in board to remind gamer which letter is wrong
    private void wrongLetter(){

        String wrongLetter = txtLetter.getText();
        String wrongLetterLabel = jLabel4.getText();
        String showWrongLetter ="";
        if(wrongLetterLabel == null){
           showWrongLetter = wrongLetterLabel + " " + wrongLetter;
        }else{
             showWrongLetter = wrongLetterLabel + ", " + wrongLetter;
        }
        jLabel4.setText(showWrongLetter);
        System.out.println(jLabel4.getText());

    }

    private void drawHangman(){
          if(countWrongLetter == 1){
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Head);
           }else if(countWrongLetter == 2){
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Head);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Left_Eye);
           }else if(countWrongLetter == 3){
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Head);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Left_Eye);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Right_Eye);
           }else if(countWrongLetter == 4){
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Head);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Left_Eye);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Right_Eye);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Mouth);
           }else if(countWrongLetter == 5){
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Head);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Left_Eye);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Right_Eye);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Mouth);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Body);
           }else if(countWrongLetter == 6){
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Head);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Left_Eye);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Right_Eye);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Mouth);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Body);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Left_Arm);
           }else if(countWrongLetter == 7){
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Head);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Left_Eye);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Right_Eye);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Mouth);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Body);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Left_Arm);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Right_Arm);
           }else if(countWrongLetter == 8){
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Head);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Left_Eye);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Right_Eye);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Mouth);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Body);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Left_Arm);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Right_Arm);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Left_Leg);
           }else if(countWrongLetter == 9 ){
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Head);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Left_Eye);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Right_Eye);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Mouth);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Body);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Left_Arm);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Right_Arm);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Left_Leg);
               DrawBodyPart(BodyPart.Right_Leg);
           }
    }

    private void btLetterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            String letter = txtLetter.getText();
            conn.getOut().println(letter);
            String inputFromServer = conn.getIn().readLine();
            System.out.println(inputFromServer);
            if(inputFromServer.equals("containt")){

                searchLetter();
                  drawHangman();
            }else{
                wrongLetter();
                countWrongLetter++;

                System.out.println(countWrongLetter);
                drawHangman();
            }


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(twoPlayers.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }                                        

    private void btReadyActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        System.out.println(getPlayerID());
    }                                       

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btLetter;
    private javax.swing.JButton btPlay;
    private javax.swing.JButton btReady;
    private javax.swing.JButton btSendChat;
    private javax.swing.JButton btWord;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JDesktopPane jDesktopPane1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtLetter;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtWord;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: what you need @ErnestFriedman-Hill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new gameHandle object for every client, so they all see the initial playerID as "000". From your description you need to share a single instance of that class between all clients.

Comment: but how to do this EJP? because i use 1 application for all clients run to play it how to share single instance of that class ?

Comment: Just create it in a different place and pass it around as an argument when creating the client thread.

Comment: can u give me example about that, it not make sense to me

Comment: @J2MENewBiew I think you should be able to do that without being spoonfed frankly. The concept is clear enough.

Comment: but i dont know how to share instance when i call this class of client

Comment: @J2MENewBiew But I've already told you. Pass it as an argument when creating the client thread object. By implication therefore, save it in the client thread object when received in its constructor.